# Printing to Email

Tags: printing, pdf, email

I would like to setup my Ubuntu 13.04 system to Have a printer that directly prints to a PDF and sends that attached to a predefined email address...etc.

How do I setup my system to best achieve this?

I have so far added CUPS-PDF package which supposedly takes care of the PDF creation but I want that PDF printer to automatically send an email to a predefined address...ideally using my Google online account and not the local mailing clients...etc.

Please help to set this all up.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsemailptr/?source=dlp
has another dependency : postcript to pdf program "ps2pdf".
Suppose it is an old project and unsure of workaround the Nails issue.

On the other hand I have a cups-pdf package installed and it happily produces pdf files under the home folder tree. The issue is how to get that sent via email silently to a preconfigured email address or even an email address prompt...ect

Answer (score 1):

From Libre office there is the option File - Send - Send as pdf. Opens pdf-export-dialogue and then your default email program.

I have never used it. Don't know if it works.

Also, there is an old project on Source Forge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsemailptr/?source=dlp

Download and extract the .tar package. Inside you can find the printer driver (email.ppd), email setup file and instructions. You will have to place the files as described in the instructions and edit the email setup file with your data.

Later you would have to open your browser and type "localhost:631" to open cups configuration. Add a new printer pointing to email.ppd as the driver.

You will have to try out and investigate the details.

Comment: Thank you for the input kleinempfaenger.

I have also opened the Readme file that comes with the http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsemailptr/?source=dlp project.

Part of the instructions like you have already written here is to copy the email.ppd file under the cups/models directory which I did.

Going forward however the instructions state to have a "backend" called nails and goiung to the link in the readmefile produces this message _As of March 2006, nail has been integrated into the Heirloom project as mailx_.